# What is the proper way to describe resources of a nested CloudFormation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-cloudformation

We have a CloudFormation script which has four nested stacks. I'm trying to describe the resources of those nested stacks. However, when I `describe-stack-resources` with the physical ID of one of the nested stacks, it only returns the "parent" stack (who's resources are just the nested stacks). This behavior is consistent in the JavaScript SDK and the AWS CLI.

Am I doing this right? Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Example AWS CLI request:

(Note: The physical resource ID requested is the second that's returned)

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --physical-resource-id arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:58701038XXXX:stack/pelorus-vk-DatabaseStack-W12E3SAXPG6K/b0197770-7519-11e6-9518-50aXXXXXca9a
{
    "StackResources": [
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:58701038XXXX:stack/pelorus-vk/f93b5960-7518-11e6-8939-XXXXX0f2ad1e",
            "ResourceStatus": "UPDATE_COMPLETE",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2016-09-07T16:53:11.305Z",
            "StackName": "pelorus-vk",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:58701038XXXX:stack/pelorus-vk-DashboardStack-1GDLBCAFE6U3F/fb9c53d0-7518-11e6-bd48-50dXXXXX84d2",
            "LogicalResourceId": "DashboardStack"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:58701038XXXX:stack/pelorus-vk/f93b5960-7518-11e6-8939-XXXXX0f2ad1e",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2016-09-07T16:53:04.667Z",
            "StackName": "pelorus-vk",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:58701038XXXX:stack/pelorus-vk-DatabaseStack-W12E3SAXPG6K/b0197770-7519-11e6-9518-50aXXXXXca9a",
            "LogicalResourceId": "DatabaseStack"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:58701038XXXX:stack/pelorus-vk/f93b5960-7518-11e6-8939-XXXXX0f2ad1e",
            "ResourceStatus": "UPDATE_COMPLETE",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2016-09-07T16:53:13.293Z",
            "StackName": "pelorus-vk",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:58701038XXXX:stack/pelorus-vk-EventProcessingStack-GB814FASNNV4/fb8f3470-7518-11e6-a2c5-503XXXXXadae",
            "LogicalResourceId": "EventProcessingStack"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:587010381366:stack/pelorus-vk/f93b5960-7518-11e6-8939-XXXXX0f2ad1e",
            "ResourceStatus": "UPDATE_COMPLETE",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2016-09-07T16:53:11.496Z",
            "StackName": "pelorus-vk",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:587010381366:stack/pelorus-vk-StreamStack-NAA3DJMELCFG/04990c30-7519-11e6-934e-50aXXXXX12f2",
            "LogicalResourceId": "StreamStack"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A potential workaround: Replacing `--physical-resource-id` with `--stack-name` results in the behavior that I expected, even though I provided the physical ID